# How can i optimize this python code to reduce time complexity

Tags: python, list, optimization

I'm Trying To Solve A Problem.

Given 2 arrays of integers, A and B, both of size n.

Suppose you have a list of integers, initially empty. Now, you traverse the 2 arrays simultaneously for every i from 1 to n, and perform the following operation:

You append Ai to the list.
If the list now contains at least Bi distinct elements, you will remove Bi distinct elements from the list. If the list has more than Bi distinct elements, you will remove Bi distinct elements ordered by the frequency in the list, from highest frequency to lowest i.e. element with a higher frequency is removed first.
If 2 elements have the same frequency in the list, then you will remove the element with the lower value of Ai.
If you can perform this removal operation, then it is counted as a successful operation, else it is unsuccessful.
Note that in case of a successful operation, the updated list, from which Bi distinct elements have been removed, is taken for the next operation.

Example

Assumptions

n = 4

A = [1, 1, 2, 3]

B = [3, 2, 3, 2]

Approach

Initially, the list is empty.
For i = 1, you first append A1 to the list. So, the list becomes [1]. Now, B1 = 3, that is, you need at least 3 distinct elements in the list. So, the operation is unsuccessful.
For i = 2, you first append A2 to the list. So, the list becomes [1, 1]. Now, B2=2, that is, you need at least 2 distinct elements in the list, but the list has only 1 distinct element. So, the operation is unsuccessful.
For i = 3, you first append A3 to the list. So, list becomes [1, 1, 2]. Now, B3 = 3, that is, you need to remove at least 3 distinct elements in the list, but the list has 2 distinct elements. So, the operation is unsuccessful.
For i = 4, you first append A4 to the list. So, the list becomes [1, 1, 2, 3]. Now, B4 = 2, that is, you need to remove at least 2 distinct elements from the list, and the list has 3 distinct elements. So, the operation is successful. You remove a 1 as it has the highest frequency in the list, and then we remove 2 as it has a lower value than 3. So, the updated list is [1, 3].
Hence, the answer, which is the number of successful operations, is 1.

The Below Is My Code Its Working fine for small cases. But FOr higher cases it giving time limit exceeded.

```
T = int(input())# No of test cases
for _ in range(T):
    N = int(input()) # Numbers of Elements in Array
    A = list(map(int,input().split()))
    B = list(map(int,input().split()))
    Lis = [] #New List
    Sucess = 0
    for i in range(N):
        Lis.append(A[i])
        if(len(set(Lis))>=B[i]):
            Lis = sorted(Lis,key=Lis.count,reverse = True)
            Set = []
            for S in Lis:
                if S not in Set:
                    Set.append(S)
                if(len(Set)==B[i]):
                    break
            for K in range(B[i]):
                Lis.remove(Set[K])
            Sucess += 1
    print(Sucess)
```

```
Input

1
4
1 1 2 3
3 2 3 2

Output

1
```

How can i optimize this code further?

Comment: You should look into data structures and python types that are more suitable for what you are doing, such as `set` or `dict`, something that has O(1) complexity for checking whether a value is in the data or not, and don't need to be iterated over and sorted on each operation

Comment: @shevron For Checking distinct elements in list i use set first. but if i use set how can remove elements in list. if i have list [3,3,1,2] as per question if B[i]=2 i have to remove 2 distinct elements from that list it makes it [3,2] if i made set of this it becomes {1,2,3} how can i remove in that order with that?

Comment: Obviously you need to be a bit more creative here, either try to combine multiple data structures (e.g. a set to keep unique items and another data structure to keep track of order / count), or try to use something more complex and specific to your case such as a Counter (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @shevron Thanks for that!! I can modify Set As ```Set = list(dict.fromkeys(Lis))```. is there anymore optimization i can do for code apart from this?

Comment: I'm sure there are but that's not how StackOverflow works. Post a specific code-related question, and you'll get specific answers. A generic "how can I optimize" this question is hard to answer - read about specialized data structures and the complexity of doing certain operations on them, and I'm sure you'll find the answer or at least come up with more specific questions.

Comment: @shevron Yeah Sure!! Thanks for ur time